# perl not print properly/incomplete

Tags: perl

i tried to print something variable. but sometime it will print delay or incomplete. below is my part of my code.

```
my $ltc1v = $data->{PartNumber}->{rev} . "\n";
chomp $ltc1v;

($result)=$check1=~ /:\s*(.+)$/; 

print "{{ $result }}\n";
print "{{ $ltc1v }}\n";

if ($result eq $ltc1v ) 
{}
```

sometime result show good and able to match if condition.

```
{{ 0x000b }}
{{ 0x000b }}
```

but sometime it will show as below and not able to match if condition.

```
 }}0x000b
{{ 0x000b }}
```

FYI, i used below command to auto flushing as well

```
$| = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like sometimes your data ends with a carriage return character.  You can remove that with `$result =~ y/\r//d;`.

Or don't include it in what you match:

```
($result)=$check1=~ /:\s*(.+?)\r?$/;
```

Comment: yes, you right. because of the return carriage. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I will add my standard recommendation here:

Whenever you are not sure why your output doesn't look like you expect, check what your data contains.

```
use Data::Dumper;
local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
print Dumper $result;
# print Dumper \@array, \%hash;
```

[perldoc Data::Dumper](https://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html)

Answer (score 0):

`$check1` contains a Carriage Return.

If you have `chomp($check1);`, replace it with `$check1 =~ s/\s+\z//;`.

If you don't have `chomp($check1);`, just add `$check1 =~ s/\s+\z//;`.

Comment: i have used chopm, but still not working. but after replace with `$check1 =~ s/\s+\z//;` it is work now.

can i know what are the different between two?

Comment: The substitution removes trailing whitespace characters.